# RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager - layouting items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple layout with a recycler. I feed it with Adapter and set `GridLayoutManager` for the recycler.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/scripts_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
tools:listitem="@layout/tmpl_script"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
app:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Activity

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.scripts_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
int columns = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.scripts_columns);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, columns));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Item

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="@drawable/game_border"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

I have two problems:

1. there is no space between rows
2. items are not centered within the row

I tried all properties in Android Studio but they do not have any effect. I googled, opened many questions but I still have no luck. What magic property shall I use?

As you can see items are positioned on left side of the screen. I want to move it to center. And there is no space between first and second row.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Anybody with idea, how to center items? I will add another picture with single column.

Comment: Maybe pass a custom layout params with gravity=center? But I have not found a setter.

Comment: I swapped to a GridView and tiles are centered finally.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for (1) is to add top and/or bottom margin, like @suraj said.

Regarding (2) - the critical issue is that your items are square. To get it working, set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and change the design of your items to use the actual smaller dimension (width or height) for both dimensions (maybe all you need to do in your case is to make the background square). Then display the content centered within the item's LinearLayout (you are already doing this). You have to do it this way because GridLayoutManager does not support layout_gravity at this time.

Comment: I figured. But since I ran into the same problem as you, with the same detail of a square view, I decided to figure it out and help out the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0):

**For 1.there is no space between rows**

Try `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"` in the linear layout of item.This should provide the spacing below each item.

**For 2.items are not centered within the row**

Looks like you have given right margin to your recyclerview and no left margin.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
```

should give equal spacing on both sides.
or set

```
app:layout_gravity="center"
```

in linear layout of the item.

Comment: ad 1) thanks, this works. Why does not it work at parent container?

Comment: you are refering to 1 or 2?

Comment: ad 2) this could make it better but I want to center the items regardless of current dimensions.

Comment: the items were centered with respect  to the parent(recyclerview). The parent itself was to the side.

Comment: sry.. layout_gravity is centering the grid with respect to the recyclerview

Comment: Recycler view's width is match_parent, so it must cover complete screen size. When I turn layout to portrait with 2 columns, it is more evident. I will post a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130880/discussion-between-suraj-rao-and-leos-literak).